# Android app usage duration and timestamp

Tags: android

I am developing an android app where whenever I use an app, the timestamp and duration of it should be displayed.

For example,

```
Facebook     12:59        5 mins
Quora        1:30         2 mins
Facebook     1:45         3 mins
```

I decided to get the last used timestamps using [Usage Stats API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/package-summary) and store it in a local copy, that way I can get an array of all the timestamps used from a particular app(For example, Facebook 12:59 and 1:45) and retrieve it in my app , but I am not able to figure out how to find the duration of the app usage ?

Comment: if you get `12:59 and 1:45` simply make the difference like this:String `time1 = "";
String time2 = "";

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date date1 = format.parse(time1);
Date date2 = format.parse(time2);
long difference = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();`

Comment: @Eminem Both times are independent from each other, the user uses the app from 12:59 to 1:04, so the duration is 5 mins...then the user uses from 1:45 to 1:48, for that duration is 3 mins, so I basically I want the end timestamp too

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html#INTERVAL_DAILY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24);

long start = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
List<UsageStats> stats = usageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, start, end);
```

You can also check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html#INTERVAL_DAILY) for more